# Port published via Docker -- can't connect

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run `jupyter/jupyter-notebook` in a Docker container.

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --detach --name jupyter \
  --publish 4000:8888 \
  --volume /root/docker/jupyter:/home/jovyan \
  jupyter/tensorflow-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password='sha1:XXXXXXX...'
```

However, something seems to go wrong.

```
root@vmd16038:~/docker# wget 0.0.0.0:4000
--2016-12-30 11:55:32--  http://0.0.0.0:4000/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:4000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

It works when I do it from inside the container though.

```
root@vmd16038:~/docker# docker exec -it jupyter wget localhost:8888
--2016-12-30 10:58:54--  http://localhost:8888/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /tree [following]
--2016-12-30 10:58:54--  http://localhost:8888/tree
Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:8888.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /login?next=%2Ftree [following]
--2016-12-30 10:58:54--  http://localhost:8888/login?next=%2Ftree
Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:8888.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5176 (5.1K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                       100%[==========================================================>]   5.05K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2016-12-30 10:58:54 (562 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [5176/5176]
```

Output of `docker ps`

```
65edf25e4de4        jupyter/tensorflow-notebook    "tini -- start-notebo"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:4000->8888/tcp
```

What could be going wrong here? I'm quite new to Docker and I don't know how to debug this problem.

---

Update: As requested by @cen, `docker inspect jupyter`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36",
        "Created": "2016-12-30T11:02:33.95435373Z",
        "Path": "tini",
        "Args": [
            "--",
            "start-notebook.sh",
            "--NotebookApp.password=sha1:XXXXXXXXX..."
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 21923,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-12-30T11:02:34.250859339Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:6f160f85eb62403786a30639eedd63412e8381a10d492a378c07f220e9332336",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36/af3f5185f0a84f151fa3889eb0f6133403b9c85838d4027a256f07b904ea9f36-json.log",
        "Name": "/jupyter",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/root/docker/jupyter:/home/jovyan"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8888/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "4000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/root/docker/jupyter",
                "Destination": "/home/jovyan",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "af3f5185f0a8",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "jovyan",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8888/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive",
                "CONDA_DIR=/opt/conda",
                "SHELL=/bin/bash",
                "NB_USER=jovyan",
                "NB_UID=1000",
                "HOME=/home/jovyan",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8",
                "XDG_CACHE_HOME=/home/jovyan/.cache/"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "start-notebook.sh",
                "--NotebookApp.password=sha1:XXXXXXXXX..."
            ],
            "Image": "jupyter/tensorflow-notebook",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/jovyan/work",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "tini",
                "--"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "1101443ef853ceecafa98b81ddf5598a35af6c68dbb76ec54dcbe3d11453c467",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8888/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "4000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/1101443ef853",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "331bbeaa9e0d5b447e76d87224f2685b4fdcf33ef96f3d1918093f8c3760a8e1",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "a762e41b430703ebc04210030c60988c92fcd64aa0ab224e779f2523e51de1a3",
                    "EndpointID": "331bbeaa9e0d5b447e76d87224f2685b4fdcf33ef96f3d1918093f8c3760a8e1",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And `netstat -nat | grep 4000`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Can you provide `docker inspect` and `netstat -nat | grep 4000`?

Comment: Docker and ports seem fine. "Connection reset by peer" apparently means that the HTTP server closed the connection which means you do actually have the connection to the container but the application does not like something about your request. I don't know what jupyter is but maybe it has some connection restrictions, eg: deny all connections not on localhost? Postgres would be one such example that does it by default.

Comment: Thanks @cen. It seems to be an issue with the application.

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` means that it is listening on all IP addresses, it is not valid as a destination for sending HTTP requests. Please try the following on the Docker host machine.

```
$ wget localhost:4000
```

Comment: I get the same result as with `0.0.0.0:4000`.

Comment: It looks strange. Look carefully at the error message again, it is as follows

Comment: `Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.` This is a possible HTTP level problem. What is the HTTP response header with `wget -S localhost: 4000` ?

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong IP address `wget 0.0.0.0:4000` instead of it use

`localhost:4000` or `eth0(IP):4000`